# Configuration of the radio on urban terror?

Tags: urban-terror

I want to change the voice commands on my charater's radio... but I lost the page where shows me where to edit... 
Actually I found it once but now I want to edit it again:

```
bind F1 "vote yes"
bind F2 "vote no"
bind F3 "ut_radio 9 9"
bind F4 "ut_radio 9 1"
bind F5 "ut_radio 3 3 Requesting medic. Status: $health"
bind F6 "ut_radio 7 4 // Base overrun"
bind F7 "ut_radio 7 5"
bind F8 "ut_radio 3 7"
bind F9 "ut_radio 2 6"
bind F10 "ut_radio 9 4"
```

F3 one is thanks, F5 is medic and so... but I want to see the other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out what I wanted:

```
1  Radio Command Chart
Menu 1  Responses
ut_radio 1 1    Affirmative.
ut_radio 1 2    Negative.
ut_radio 1 3    I'm on it!
ut_radio 1 4    Area secured.
ut_radio 1 5    Base is secure.
ut_radio 1 6    Medic on the way, hang in there.
ut_radio 1 7    I've got your back.
ut_radio 1 8    Enemy terminated.
Menu 2  Orders
ut_radio 2 1    Move in.
ut_radio 2 2    Fall back and regroup!
ut_radio 2 3    Hold your position.
ut_radio 2 4    Stick with me.
ut_radio 2 5    Cover me.
ut_radio 2 6    Requesting backup.
ut_radio 2 7    Go for the objective.
ut_radio 2 8    Flank them!
ut_radio 2 9    Double time, let's move!



Menu 3  Conditions
ut_radio 3 1    I'm moving in.
ut_radio 3 2    Awaiting orders.
ut_radio 3 3    I need a medic!
ut_radio 3 4    Objective in sight.
ut_radio 3 5    Objective is clear.
ut_radio 3 6    I'm attacking.
ut_radio 3 7    I'm defending.
ut_radio 3 8    I'm flanking.
ut_radio 3 9    Holding here.
Menu 4  Queries
ut_radio 4 1    Status?
ut_radio 4 2    Objective status?
ut_radio 4 3    Base status?
ut_radio 4 4    Where's the enemy?
ut_radio 4 5    Where are the medics?
ut_radio 4 6    Anyone need support?
ut_radio 4 7    Anyone need a medic?
ut_radio 4 8    Who's ya daddy?
ut_radio 4 9    How the hell are ya?



Menu 5  Enemy Activity
ut_radio 5 1    Enemy spotted.
ut_radio 5 2    Enemy heard.
ut_radio 5 3    Enemy is flanking!
ut_radio 5 4    Enemy headed your way!
ut_radio 5 5    Incoming!
ut_radio 5 9    Objective in danger!
Menu 6  Directional
ut_radio 6 1    North.
ut_radio 6 2    South.
ut_radio 6 3    East.
ut_radio 6 4    West.
ut_radio 6 5    base.
ut_radio 6 6    High.
ut_radio 6 7    Low.
ut_radio 6 8    Water.
ut_radio 6 9    Here.



Menu 7  Capture the Flag
ut_radio 7 1    I've got the flag.
ut_radio 7 2    I'm going for the flag.
ut_radio 7 3    They have our flag.
ut_radio 7 4    Base is being overrun!
ut_radio 7 5    Recover the flag!
ut_radio 7 6    Flag exiting left.
ut_radio 7 7    Flag exiting right.
ut_radio 7 8    Flag exiting front.
ut_radio 7 9    Flag exiting back.
Menu 8  Bomb
ut_radio 8 1    Heading to Bombsite A.
ut_radio 8 2    Heading to Bombsite B.
ut_radio 8 3    Enemy at Bombsite A.
ut_radio 8 4    Enemy at Bombsite B.
ut_radio 8 5    I have the bomb.
ut_radio 8 6    The bomb is loose!



Menu 9  Miscellaneous
ut_radio 9 1    Good job team.
ut_radio 9 2    Nice one.
ut_radio 9 3    Check your fire!
ut_radio 9 4    Sorry about that.
ut_radio 9 5    Whatever.
ut_radio 9 6    No problem.
ut_radio 9 7    Oh, you idiot!
ut_radio 9 8    What the f*ck, over?
ut_radio 9 9    Thanks.
```

just add that comand in your `q3config.cfg` file.

like this:

```
bind F3 "ut_radio 9 9"
bind F4 "ut_radio 9 1"
bind F5 "ut_radio 3 3 Requesting medic. Status: $health"
bind F6 "ut_radio 7 4 // Base overrun"
bind F7 "ut_radio 7 5"
bind F8 "ut_radio 3 7"
bind F9 "ut_radio 2 6"
bind F10 "ut_radio 9 4"
```

read [this](http://www.urbanterror.info/support/109-user-interface/?show=radio).